# Los input se desplazan al salir el texto de validación

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo un problema en un formulario dinámico al hacer `submit`. El problema se da que en el momento de validar los campos si uno de ellos tiene un texto a mostrar de la validación errónea, entonces desplaza el `input` de abajo hacia un lado.
parece ser que ocurre cuando el formulario, (que se genera dinamicamante) tiene  un numero de inputs impares

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="@item.Label" class="control-label">
        @item.Label  @((bool)item.prop ? " (*):" : ":")
      </label>
    </div>
  <div>                                      
}
```

¿Como puedo controlar esto?

Comment: Por favor añade el código HTML generado para que podamos ver el problema. Lee "[Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" en el centro de ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que al momento de salir el mensaje de error en `div` tiende a hacerse mas grande, suponiendo que tu código generado es como el siguiente:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="item.Label" class="control-label">
        texto1
      </label>
      <span class="help-block">Mensaje de error</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="item.Label" class="control-label">
        texto2
      </label>
      <span class="help-block"></span><!--otro mensaje de error no asignado y ocultado-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="@item.Label" class="control-label">
        texto3
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="item.Label" class="control-label">
        texto4
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que yo te recomiendo es que pongas un div con la clase `.row` por cada 2 elementos con la clase `.col-md-6`.

```
int cont = 0;
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  if(cont%2==0){
    <div class="row">
  }
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="@item.Label" class="control-label">
        @item.Label  @((bool)item.prop ? " (*):" : ":")
      </label>
    </div>
  <div>
  if(cont%2==0){
    </div>
  }  
  cont++;                                    
}
```

Tu salida seria como esto:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="item.Label" class="control-label">
        texto1
      </label>
      <!-- Mostrando el mensaje de error -->
      <span class="help-block">Mensaje de error</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="item.Label" class="control-label">
        texto2
      </label>
      <span class="help-block"></span><!--otro mensaje de error no asignado y ocultado-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class"row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="@item.Label" class="control-label">
        texto3
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="item.Label" class="control-label">
        texto4
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Nota:

He cambiado la clase `.col-md-6` por `.col-xs-6` para que fuera visible en el snipet.
El código del `foreach` no se si valla a ser funcional pero espero entiendas la idea

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue perfecto!